# Select multiple column from different directory and then merge them in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have a directory and in my directory there are multiple files. Each file having different csv. For example in my directory there is 5 files (in actual case more than 100), and each file having 10 .csv file.

My question is that I want to select different columns (all files having equal no of columns) from that files and merge them and create a single data frame.

My data frame looks like -

Main Directory -

```
File1-

a.csv -

 store_code  Tran1  Tran2  Tran3
     10       5454   7645   7111
     10       4154   7675   7000
     10       1454   2145   8431
      .........

b.csv -

 store_code  Tran1  Tran2  Tran3
     10       5004   6645   7291
     10       4109   1675   7000
     10       9454   1045   1031
      .........

 File2-

 c.csv - 

 store_code  Tran1  Tran2  Tran3
     20       1054   2045   1111
     20       2954   3075   7080
     20       1454   2145   8431
      .........

  d.csv - 

 store_code  Tran1  Tran2  Tran3
     20       1994   2045   9011
     20       2004   3075   8080
     20       1004   2145   1031
      .........
```

I have done the merging of all files from a directory. But unable do select multiple column and then merge. For this example suppose I want to select two columns store_code and Tran2 and then merge all them.

For merging purpose I have done the following code -

```
i.Main directory set as a working directory where all files are there.
ii.csv_files <- dir(pattern='.*[.]csv', recursive = T)

library(dplyr)
df <- rbind_all(lapply(csv_files, read.csv))
```

My expected output -

```
store_code    Tran3 
10            7111 
10            7000 
10            1111  
..            ---- 
20            9011
20            8080
```

Comment: You've got two columns labelled `Tran2` in every CSV file. Is that a typo?

Comment: So you only want to read 2 columns from each file then merge all together?

Comment: @Tung - you are correct..

Comment: @Maurits - Typo..Tran3

Comment: Your expected output is not useful. Please **format** your code properly, and provide the output that are expecting **based on your sample data**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after; unfortunately you don't provide your expected output.

Perhaps something like this?

```
library(tidyverse);
Reduce(
    function(x, y) full_join(x, y, by = c("store_code", "Tran2")),
    lapply(csv_files, read.csv));
#  store_code Tran1.x Tran2 Tran3.x Tran1.y Tran3.y Tran1.x.x Tran3.x.x
#1         10    5454  7645    7111      NA      NA        NA        NA
#2         10    4154  7675    7000      NA      NA        NA        NA
#3         10    1454  2145    8431      NA      NA        NA        NA
#4         10      NA  6645      NA    5004    7291        NA        NA
#5         10      NA  1675      NA    4109    7000        NA        NA
#6         10      NA  1045      NA    9454    1031        NA        NA
#7         20      NA  2045      NA      NA      NA      1054      1111
#8         20      NA  3075      NA      NA      NA      2954      7080
#9         20      NA  2145      NA      NA      NA      1454      8431
#  Tran1.y.y Tran3.y.y
#1        NA        NA
#2        NA        NA
#3        NA        NA
#4        NA        NA
#5        NA        NA
#6        NA        NA
#7      1994      9011
#8      2004      8080
#9      1004      1031
```

Explanation: Do an outer `full_join` on all CSV files, merge by `store_code` and `Tran2`. Because you have two `Tran2` columns per file, I've relabelled the last column as `Tran3`.

From here, all that's left to do is some tidying and renaming of columns to reflect the source file origin.

---

### Sample data

This is the `dput` of `lapply(csv_files, read.csv)`:

```
list(structure(list(store_code = c(10L, 10L, 10L), Tran1 = c(5454L,
4154L, 1454L), Tran2 = c(7645L, 7675L, 2145L), Tran3 = c(7111L,
7000L, 8431L)), .Names = c("store_code", "Tran1", "Tran2", "Tran3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
store_code = c(10L, 10L, 10L), Tran1 = c(5004L, 4109L, 9454L
), Tran2 = c(6645L, 1675L, 1045L), Tran3 = c(7291L, 7000L,
1031L)), .Names = c("store_code", "Tran1", "Tran2", "Tran3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
store_code = c(20L, 20L, 20L), Tran1 = c(1054L, 2954L, 1454L
), Tran2 = c(2045L, 3075L, 2145L), Tran3 = c(1111L, 7080L,
8431L)), .Names = c("store_code", "Tran1", "Tran2", "Tran3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(
store_code = c(20L, 20L, 20L), Tran1 = c(1994L, 2004L, 1004L
), Tran2 = c(2045L, 3075L, 2145L), Tran3 = c(9011L, 8080L,
1031L)), .Names = c("store_code", "Tran1", "Tran2", "Tran3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))
```

Comment: My expected output looks like -

store_code    Tran2
  10                7645   
  10                7000
  10                2145
...........................

  10                 6645
  10                 1675
-----------------------

Means only two columns with all merged row.

Comment: I mistake from my end is ..last column name is Tran3..I run your code but it's not working...I think know what is my expected output..any solutions?

Comment: @NikitaAgarwal Don't put code in comments. Edit your question to include your expected output. See [here how to provide a minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data and expected output.